# RTL with tabluar

Tags: tables, xetex, lyx, bidi

This is a question about **xelatex**, even though I mention LyX here.

My goal is to produce an RTL table with one row, two columns, which looks more or less like that:

```
                                                                      +---+---+
                                                                      | 2 | 1 |
                                                                      +---+---+
```

I tried to produce it in LyX and then exported to XeTeX and got the following code:

```
%% LyX 2.0.8.1 created this file.  For more info, see http://www.lyx.org/.
%% Do not edit unless you really know what you are doing.
\documentclass[english,hebrew]{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont[Mapping=tex-text]{David CLM}

\makeatletter

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% LyX specific LaTeX commands.
%% Because html converters don't know tabularnewline
\providecommand{\tabularnewline}{\\}

\makeatother

\usepackage{xunicode}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage{hebrew}
\setotherlanguage{english}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|}
\hline 
{\beginL 2\endL} & {\beginL 1\endL}\tabularnewline
\hline 
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

It seems opposite, and indeed, when compiling this tex file with **xelatex** I get an opposite table:

```
                                                                      +---+---+
                                                                      | 1 | 2 |
                                                                      +---+---+
```

So I figured out this is a [LyX bug](http://www.lyx.org/trac/ticket/9686), but before "solving" it, LyX people like to be sure what the correct XeTeX code should be.  Is it simply the columns switched, as I thought?  Or perhaps something else is wrong there?

Comment: It could be a "feature" rather than a bug.

Comment: @JohnKormylo but I'm not sure the on-screen LyX display should be different from the PDF display.

Comment: From my understanding, the table itself is not entered RTL in the source, but LTR and then will automatically be made RTL by `bidi`. (Also the `\beginL` and `\endL` code isn't necessary, nor are the global language options, (and a few other things) but I assume you can't change this since it's generated by LyX.

Comment: @AlanMunn how would one enter the table RTL in the source?

Comment: @scottkosty I don't know about LyX but in the code above the first column at the left will be the first column on the right when typeset in RTL mode.

Comment: @AlanMunn I see. We're trying to figure out what code LyX should ideally produce. Imagine a GUI where you have a table that is marked as Hebrew (so the GUI knows it should be RTL). The user puts 2 in the left column and 1 in the right column, and thus the output should be the same. What is the best way to get that output? One way is to produce the same LaTeX as above but just flip the entries 2 and 1 in the LaTeX code. However, I wonder if there is better code that could be produced.

Comment: @scottkosty yes that's what I meant. The `bidi` package sets tables RTL in RTL mode and the same table LTR in LTR mode.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By writing `\setdefaultlanguage{hebrew}` you set the entire document Right-to-Left by default, which affects also the order of table columns. This has to do with the `bidi` package that is loaded by `polyglossia`. By the way, the commands `\beginL` and `\endL` are not needed when using these packages.

So, LyX  should produce the opposite columns order in RTL mode. 
 Note also that if you load `polyglossia` you don't need to load `fontspec` not `xunicode`.

So the code should be the following:

```
\documentclass[english,hebrew]{article}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainfont[Mapping=tex-text]{David CLM}

\providecommand{\tabularnewline}{\\}

\setdefaultlanguage{hebrew}
\setotherlanguage{english}


\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|}
\hline 
1 & 2 \tabularnewline
\hline 
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks Ariel. Let's see if I understand this (I'm new to RTL and bidi) --- The reason why we input it LTR into LaTeX is because that is what we "mean". That is, we mean that 1 should be in "row 1" and 2 should be in "row 2". When we compile, "row 1" is determined to start from the right because it is RTL. Is that the correct intuition?

Comment: @scottkosty Yes, that's a good way of thinking about it. (Substituting 'column' for 'row', which I assume is what you meant.)

Comment: @AlanMunn Ah yes thanks for the correction. OK this is good to know.

Comment: Can you confirm that when you say "are not needed when using these packages", that `\beginL` and `\endL` are *never* useful when using the `polyglossia` package? From what I understand, polyglossia is smart and knows that e.g. Hebrew should be RTL so it is not necessary to say it explicitly. I guess that babel is not as smart and that is why it is necessary with babel?

Comment: @scottkosty `bidi` uses `\beginL` etc. internally, but they are not user level commands in general. `bidi` does provide different user level commands and environments for embedding RTL text within LTR and vice versa. I know nothing about RTL languages and `babel` so I can't help you with your second question.

Comment: @scottkosty, when you use `ployglossia` you don't need to use these commands or the commands provided by `bidi` (`\RL` and `\LR`). Rather, you enclose the text in Hebrew with the command `\texthebrew{...}` and similarly for other languages (or alternatively with an enivorment `\begin{hebrew}`. If you define your default language to be Hebrew this is not needed of course. A prequisite for this, however, is to define a font supporting Hebrew, with the command `\newfontfamily\hebrewfont[Script=Hebrew]{font name}`

Comment: @Ariel OK, thanks to Ariel and Alan for the advice. We will look into implementing more proper support in LyX.

Answer (score -1):

The easy way is:

Write your table like this

```
                                                                      +---+---+
                                                                  | 1 | 2 |
                                                                  +---+---+
```

After you generate pdf you get:

```
                                                                      +---+---+
                                                                  | 2 | 1 |
                                                                  +---+---+
```

I used this idea always time.

Comment: Your answer is not so clear. How do you write the table in the Latex code?